# What does the 1.-np.arange() mean in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, function, methods, numpy-ndarray

I have the following line of code given to me as part of an example in my python course

> np.sqrt(1.-np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)**2)

But there have been no explanations given. I am confused as to what the 1.-np.arange() means? So before this I was not aware that you can do 1. and then have the function np.arange() next to it, let alone have a negative sign before the function and after the float 1.

How does this line of code work? Furthermore, may you give me some examples of other functions where I can do this or can you point me in the right direction as to where I can learn more about this (so that I can use it in other scenarios with other functions)?

I went to the documentation for numpy.arange() and I didn't find anything. I put the following line of code into Jupyter notebook and found that it returned an array of some negative numbers, with the first two numbers being 1 and 0. I was expecting it to not work as I have not come across it before. In fact I thought it was a typo in the notes that I was given but it appears not.

> print(1.-np.arange(0,100,1))

Comment: What do you mean "I went to the documentation... and didn't find anything".  I typed `numpy.arange` into Google, and it took me to a page that told me exactly what it did, including examples.

Comment: `arange` returns a numpy array. A numpy array combined with an arithmetic operator and a number returns a new array containing the result of the arithmetic operations for each number in the original array.  This works regardless if the order is array, operator, number or number, operator, array.

Comment: Ohhh so it is just 1 minus every element from the array created? Okay thanks! You putting the space in between 1 and the minus sign helped me get it. I feel silly for making the post now, am not sure why I couldn't see it before.

Comment: This question should probably be deleted. I'm not sure there's any reason for it to be kept.

Comment: Often in python you can figure out what happens by finding the 'inner-most/first' function or action, and working out from there. In does require a basic understanding of python syntax, and identifiying when something is from an inported package.  Here `np.arange(4)` is the starting point.  That makes an array (small or large).  The rest is basic array math - substract from`1` (this is not a special operation on `1.`!)  Then square, and squareroot. Test it piece by piece, and look at the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to decompose the terms individually and understand them, but before doing that you need to remember that you can add/subtract scalars from numpy arrays using +/- in both directions.
So now np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01) it return an array from [0, 1] with step size 0.01 so around 101 elements, let us call it A.
Then A**2 is applying a squaring elementwist for A, so all elements will be multiplied by itself, let us call it B.
Then you subtract B from 1.0 or 1. by 1. - B, meaning if you have zero in B it will become 1 (Note here that squaring elements smaller than one will make them smaller than before which means that all the values are still positive), let us call it C.
Finally, you apply sqrt to C which is all positive values and you get your result.

```
result = np.sqrt(1.-np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)**2)
# OR
A = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
B = A**2
C = 1.0 - B
result = np.sqrt(C)
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I realised tbat I was confused since I thought 1. meant it was a method with the numpy function, which didn't make sense to me. I understand now thanks!